# is it possible to write a surface view without creating thread?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I want to write a surface View without creating a thread. is it possible to create a surfaceview ,without calling it from thread. if possible, please provide me a simple example.

Comment: Sure it's possible, just drop the thread. You won't see much then though...

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't entirely make sense to me, but I'll try to answer what I think you're asking.

Yes, you can draw on a `SurfaceView` without creating a dedicated thread.  This is not the recommended approach; you should do your rendering off the main thread so that the app doesn't become slow to respond, but it's not an absolute requirement.

I don't know if it counts as a "simple" example, but [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "multi-surface test" draws on three overlapping `SurfaceViews` from the UI thread.  These are static images, drawn once, so there's not really a need for a separate thread.  If you start an animation on one of the surfaces (with the "bounce" button) it kicks off a new thread, because it's just easier to manage that way.